# timedeltas for a groupby column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, pandas-groupby

For a given data frame `df`

```
timestamps = [
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0), # person 1
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0), # person 2
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 11, 0, 0, 0), # person 2
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0), # person 2
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1, 10, 0, 0, 0), # person 3
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 11, 0, 0, 0), # person 3
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 4, 10, 0, 0, 0), # person 3
    datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 5, 12, 0, 0, 0)  # person 3
]
df = pd.DataFrame({'person': [1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3], 'timestamp': timestamps })
```

I want to calculate for each person (`df.groupby('person')`) the time differences between all timestamps of that person, which I would to with [`diff()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

```
df.groupby('person').timestamp.diff()
```

is just half the way, because the mapping back to the person is lost.

How could a solution look like?

Comment: No, not really a duplicate. I missed that point that I need `transform` for the `diff`. That is the answer to my question.

Comment: Have you *actually tried* the above dup? It works fine..

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my question, I did exactly this (using `diff()`), but this was not the proper solution. As @jezreal pointed out I missed that diff does not aggregate values, but transform does.

Comment: I think this is a case of user error. If you apply logic *exactly as described in the post*, it works. I know, because I checked. I'll post an example here.

Comment: My apologies, indeed, it was my error! Sorry about that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem `diff` no aggregate values, so possible solution is [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html):

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('person').timestamp.transform(pd.Series.diff)
print (df)
   person           timestamp             new
0       1 2018-01-01 10:00:00             NaT
1       2 2018-01-01 10:00:00             NaT
2       2 2018-01-01 11:00:00 0 days 01:00:00
3       2 2018-01-02 11:00:00 1 days 00:00:00
4       3 2018-01-01 10:00:00             NaT
5       3 2018-01-02 11:00:00 1 days 01:00:00
6       3 2018-01-04 10:00:00 1 days 23:00:00
7       3 2018-01-05 12:00:00 1 days 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

i think you should use

`df.groupby('person').timestamp.transform(pd.Series.diff)`